# How to properly sanitize the input from an admin form on save and when referenced in controller class?

Tags: 8

We have an admin form that has two text fields ('pattern' and 'host'). In a ControllerClass we have to use the input to perform some logic.

How would we properly sanitize the input from the two text fields on save of text field values and when retrieving the value in a controller class?

Current code:

```
class MyModule extends ProviderPluginBase {
  public function _some_function($input) {
    $mymodule_config = \Drupal::config('mymodule.settings');
    $host = $mymodule_config->get('host');
    $pattern = $mymodule_config->get('pattern');

    /* we will need to use the $host and $pattern */
}
```

We initially thought that [HTML::escape](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21Html.php/function/Html%3A%3Aescape/8.4.x) would work, but that is for output. Not sure how to sanitize the input.

Example of what we tried for the controller class:

```
$escapted_value = _some_sanitization_function($pattern);
```

When saving the text field value:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');
  $config
    ->set('pattern', _some_sanitization_function($form_state->getValue('pattern'))
    ->set('host', _some_sanitization_function($form_state->getValue('host'))
    ->save();
}
```

Comment: Always escape on output, not input. If the text is rendered in a template as a variable, that will happen automatically. The docs are here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/security/writing-secure-code-for-drupal-8

Comment: @Clive looks like I was confusing the purpose of the HTML::escape. What would be the `_some_sanitization_function` used to sanitize the input?

Comment: You don’t sanitise input, you always want that to be raw. Obviously use the DB abstraction layer to prevent sql injection if you’re executing queries with this input (in your code example hat doesn’t apply, you’re at a higher level of abstraction and the underlying code will take care of it), but other than that you only need to consider output. The linked docs cover it in full

Comment: @Clive that is what I thought, but when I submitted a patch to the Drupal community for a module, it was mentioned that a variables that was fetched from the `$config` needs to be sanitized. As such, I was searching for correct way to do that.

Comment: Yes it needs to be filtered for xss before being rendered. If you output it as a twig variable, `{{ foo }}`, that’s all you need. Honestly, read the linked docs they cover this very well

Comment: @Clive The values are not outputted in any twig template, only on the admin form. However, they are used in the MyModule class

Comment: Sorry you’re going to have to be a bit more specific - what we’re you told needed to be sanitised, by what method, and where/when? The only sanitisation you need to do on input is sql injection (already handled), and the only sanitisation you need to do on output is xss filtering. There are many situations where that output escaping is done for you, but without knowing the exact problem I can’t say whether you’re covered by one of them